# javascript : I want execute 1 command every X seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, bots, delay

*Hello,
I create a small twitch bot and I want to execute the following condition only once every 100 seconds for example:*

```
if (message.indexOf("emoji") !== -1) {
  client.say(channel, `emoji party`);
}
```

*but as you can see I have other similar conditions so I don't want my whole bot to be paralized for 100 seconds.
I want each condition to be time independent*

```
const tmi = require("tmi.js");

const client = new tmi.Client({
  options: { debug: true, messagesLogLevel: "info" },
  connection: {
    reconnect: true,
    secure: true
  },

  // Lack of the identity tags makes the bot anonymous and able to fetch messages from the channel
  // for reading, supervison, spying or viewing purposes only
  identity: {
    username: `${process.env.TWITCH_BOT_USERNAME}`,
    password: `oauth:${process.env.TWITCH_OAUTH_TOKEN}`
  },
  channels: ["channelName"]
});
client.connect().catch(console.error);

client.on("message", (channel, tags, message, self) => {
  if (self) return;

  if (message.indexOf("emoji") !== -1) {
    client.say(channel, `emoji party`);
  }

  if (message.indexOf("LUL") !== -1) {
    client.say(channel, `LUL LUL LUL LUL`);
  }
});
```

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like that will work for you. Im not sure how to store persistent variable but `global` might be ok.

```
global.lastEmojiPartyMs = null; // lets store last called time (milliseconds)

client.on("message", (channel, tags, message, self) => {
  if (self) return;

  if (message.indexOf("emoji") !== -1) {
    const nowMs = Date.now();
    if (
      !global.lastEmojiPartyMs ||
      nowMs - global.lastEmojiPartyMs >= 100 * 1000 // 100 seconds for example
    ) {
      global.lastEmojiPartyMs = nowMs;
      client.say(channel, `emoji party`);
    }
  }

  if (message.indexOf("LUL") !== -1) {
    client.say(channel, `LUL LUL LUL LUL`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make use of `setInterval(myFunction, 1000);`

Take a look at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) for more information